# What is a scalable way of creating cron jobs on Amazon Web Services?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

This is my first question so I appologize if it's not the best quality.

I have a use case: User creates a monitoring task which sends an http request to a website every X hours. User can have thousands of these tasks and can add/modify and delete them. When a user creates a task, django signals create a Celery periodic task which then is running periodically.

I'm searching for a more scalable solution using AWS. I've read about using Lambda + Cloudwatch Events.

My question is: how do I approach this to let my users create tens of thousands of these tasks in the cheapest / most scalable way?

Thank you for reading my question!
Peter

Comment: If i understood well , you want to give users ability to create a monitoring job which consists of sending http get request to a same website ?

Comment: hi Java, exactly that's what I'm searching for. These tasks then check a website for changes and notify the user if anything has changed. I need a solution that will allow users for creating/deleting hundreds of these tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward solution to your problem .You have to proceed step by step with some plumbing along the way .

Event management

1- Create a lambda function that creates a cloudwatch schedule.

2 - Create a lambda function that deletes a cloudwatch schedule.

3 - Persist any event created using dynamodb

4 - Create 2 API gateway  that will invoke the 2 lambda above.

5 - Create anohter lambda function (used by cloudwatch) that will invoke the API gateway below.

6 - Create API gateway that will invoke the website via http request.

When the user creates an event from the app, there will be a chaining calls as follow :

4 -> 1,3 -> 5-> 6

Now there are two other parameters to take into consideration :

Lambda concurrency: you can't run simultaneously more than 1000 lambda in same region.

Cloudwatch: You can not create more than 100 rules per region . Rule is where you define the schedule.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I upvoted it but I don't have enough reputation for the counter to change :( I've also read about the AWS SQS + Lambda for tasks to be 'pushed' into lambda once the first batch of 1K ends its execution. What do you think about it?

Comment: You can use 6 queues: one to prevent users from running into concurrency bottleneck while creating a job. Then when you created say 5 queues for controlling jobs execution. Since all jobs are in queue they get executed sequencely and since we have 5 jobs we can execute 5 parallel jobs and so on. The duration of the job execution is 1s as per your requirement (http get) , so user will not notice any difference. All aws limits can be increased upon request to dev team.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. Thanks again!